# "Take the material from January" vs. "Take the material from November"

Tags: grammar, future-tense

So let's say we are currently in June, and I am considering using materials that has been allocated to future needs. I understand that if we were to take something leftover from the past, we would use "take the materials from January," but if we want to take something from the future, can we still use "from."

"Take/use the materials from November."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Use the materials intended/reserved for November."

Comment: In your context, ***November*** is simply shorthand for *November's **allocation of materials*** or similar, as per @WeatherVane's post. Personally, I don't see how it would make sense to use a ***past*** month name in such contexts without explicitly indicating how these "not-present" materials come to be available. You'd pretty much have to say something like *Use the materials **left over** from November* unless it was in the nature of these materials that they could be ***re-*** used.

Comment: I see. Maybe I can say something like: "We'd like to use the material that has been allocated to support November's demand."